# Parse Multipart Request Body in Node.JS from Flutter Client

Tags: node.js, flutter, express, http

I am trying to send along 3 image files to my express server running on Google Cloud Functions.

I am able to get the request to go through, but it is showing up as a buffer on the server.

I am setting fields on the request that I need to grab on the server but am not sure how to parse the `req.body` properly to pull this information off.

```
  Future<dynamic> uploadPost(Map<String, dynamic> postData, String placeName,
      String placeAddress) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        "POST",
        Uri.parse('http://localhost:5001/findabite-1ac1a/us-central1/api' +
            '/posts/add'));
    request.fields['placeAddress'] = (placeAddress);
    request.fields['placeName'] = (placeName);
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    await Future.forEach(postData.keys, (data) async {
      final String key = data as String;
      if (key.startsWith('filePath')) {
        request.files.add(
          await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(key, postData[key]),
        );
      } else {
        request.fields[key] = (postData[key]);
      }
    });
    request.send();
  }
```

Am I missing something in my client implementation?

This is my express config:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const { routes } = require("./src/routes");
const errorHandler = require("./src/middlewares/error_handler");

var app = express();

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.disable("x-powered-by");

app.use(routes);
app.use(errorHandler);

module.exports = { app };
```

And this is the output of the console when I try to print `req.body`:

```
<Buffer 2d 2d 64 61 72 74 2d 68 74 74 70 2d 62 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 2d 34 68 59 48 5f 65 32 77 31 50 65 48 50 57 5f 31 31 4a 51 48 42 47 5a 39 46 4a 31 34 6b ... 309 more bytes>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multer` to upload the files to server (as a middleware) and then you can access to the body request.

[Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer, albeit not really the answer I was hoping for I wanted to post to help anybody else out that may run into the same issue.

As per the GCP documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data) there is unfortunately no easy way to send along multipart/form data to Google Cloud Functions. I tried using Busboy to send along the form data but then was not able to get the image buffer to save to Cloud Storage using the Admin SDK. I admitted defeat for the time being and essentially bypassed my server for the singular action of uploading images. Using the Flutter Firebase SDK I am able to upload the images, and get back the downloadURL which I then send to my server along with other metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with busboy. https://gist.github.com/PatrickHeneise/8f2c72c16c4e68e829e58ade64aba553#file-gcp-function-storage-file-stream-js

```
function asyncBusboy(req, res) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const storage = new Storage()
    const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.BUCKET)

    const fields = []
    const busboy = Busboy({
      headers: req.headers,
      limits: {
        fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024
      }
    })

    busboy.on('field', (key, value) => {
      fields[key] = value
    })

    busboy.on('file', (name, file, fileInfo) => {
      const { mimeType } = fileInfo
      const destFile = bucket.file(fileName)
      const writeStream = destFile.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
          contentType: fileInfo.mimeType,
          metadata: {
            originalFileName: fileInfo.filename
          }
        }
      })
      file.pipe(writeStream)
    })

    busboy.on('close', function () {
      return resolve({ fields })
    })

    if (req.rawBody) {
      busboy.end(req.rawBody)
    } else {
      req.pipe(busboy)
    }
  })
}
```